# Preequisite for compling linux kernel ontop of cygwin

Tags: cygwin

What are the prerequisite for compiling Linux on Cygwin?

Is it similar to compiling on   a  Linux PC, or do we need to add patches?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it similar to compiling on a Linux PC, or do we need to add patches?

I think de facto, it **should** be the same with mainline kernels.

The point is that you probably don't want an unmodified kernel, otherwise you wouldn't be asking how to build one. So the question is a lot more complex: Will the Linux kernel, *including everything you include which might not be maintained upstream*, compile successfully under Cygwin?

There's no telling that, and frankly, I don't even think it matters.

Virtualization is a relatively mature technology nowadays. Get yourself a Linux VM (there's many  ready-made build systems out there), get yourself a matching virtualizer (VirtualBox will totally do), and build your kernel on a running Linux. Virtualization nowadays *is* the answer to these kind of questions, IMHO, because it was meant to give you the right OS for the particular job you want to do.

Compiling the Linux kernel (that's the job) nowadays is best done on a Linux system (that's the right OS for it), period.

Comment: ya, but in our project we are having tools running only in windows, For sure i need to use cygwin instead of virtual box / vmware

Comment: Seriously, that's a bad argument. Let's make an analogy: "My job is digging a hole in a ground. I know that there are shovels, but our project already uses screwdrivers, so tell me how to screwdrive a hole in the ground". It's funky if Linux even builds with Cygwin at all!

Comment: You'd typically just set up a build server VM, and in your windows-based build process SSH into that machine, and initiate the kernel build, copying the result back to windows. Build servers are highly common these days, so have a look at Jenkins etc.

Comment: thats fine, that is apart. through cygwin there is a provision to compile linux. SO here i mainly concentrating on cygwin. Not worrying about virtual box or vmware or running linux on any other server